# Weird login page for Area 51 and Chat on iOS

Tags: bug, design, chat, area-51, login

When logging in to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) or the [chat server](https://chat.stackexchange.com) on my iPhone with my Stack Exchange credentials, the login widget (sometimes) isn't loaded correctly. The placeholders are shown a few lines below the actual input boxes:

[image]

I estimate that this happens to me 25% of the time, but I can't really figure out when. I'm using an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 11.2.6, but I'm experiencing this since at least 6-8 months so it's not a bug specific to this iOS/Safari version.